# How to remove the square border from around a button which has already been visited?

Tags: html, css

After I click one of the buttons and go back to the main page, the button that I clicked is bordered with a square blue border. How can I remove this border so that there's no square border around the circle button after I have clicked it?

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #3F6;
  border-color: #000;
  border-radius: 4em;
}
button:hover {
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" target="_blank"><button>Test</button></a>
<a href="#" target="_blank"><button>Test</button></a>
<a href="#" target="_blank"><button>Test</button></a>
<a href="#" target="_blank"><button>Test</button></a>
```

Answer (score 15):

You can simply add outline-style:none on focus in your css like this:

```
button:focus { outline-style: none; }
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/9L5M7/).

Answer (score 9):

The style you want to apply to those objects is :

```
outline: 0;
```

Or, if you want to remove from ALL, you can do this :

```
<style>
    :focus {outline:none;}
    ::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;}
</style>
```

For example :

```
<style>
input {
   outline: 0;
}

button {
   outline: 0;
}
</style>
```

For IE9 support, you should include the following meta tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

*NOTE:  If you apply the style to a base object, you do not need to apply it to the actions; so applying it using `button`, means you do not have to apply it to `button:focus`, `button:active`, etc.

### Your Code Modified - Cross browser solution working in Firefox

```css
a:focus {
   outline: 0;
}

/* added for Firefox compatability */
button::-moz-focus-inner, a::-moz-focus-inner { border:0; }

button
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#3F6;
    outline: 0;
    border-color:#000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4em;
    -moz-border-radius: 4em;
    border-radius: 4em;
}

button:hover
{
    background:#F00;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />

<title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>

<a href="#" target="_blank"><button>Test</button></a>
<a href="#" target="_blank"><button>Test</button></a>
<a href="#" target="_blank"><button>Test</button></a>
<a href="#" target="_blank"><button>Test</button></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you can view this example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xFdd6/)

Removed the top-left/right/bottom/etc and replaced with single style for all 4 corners. Also added compatible lines for cross-browser support (aka webkit, moz). Action events automatically inherit the main class (unless overridden like you see with `background:#F00;` )

Also, please read this >> [Why you shouldn't remove the dotted outline, and how to if you really must](http://www.outlinenone.com/)

The outline is for accessibility reasons.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `outline: none;`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `outline: none`, like so.

```
button:focus { outline: none; }
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w8UB8/)