# Disabled square border InputRadioGroup

Tags: c#, css, blazor

When use a Blazor InputRadioGroup component, after choice, a square border is drawn in all options - Can it disabled this, sample:

```
@page "/RatioButtons"
<h3>Ratio Buttons</h3>
<div>
    <EditForm Model="person">
        <InputRadioGroup Name="age" @bind-Value="person.Age">
            Set Age:<br />
            @for (int i = 18; i < 36; i++) {
                <InputRadio Value="@i" />
                @($" Age {i}")<br />
            }
        </InputRadioGroup>
    </EditForm>
</div>
<br />
<div class="card p-3" >
    <h5>@person.FirstName @person.LastName : @person.Age</h5>
</div>

@code {
    class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    Person person = new Person {
        FirstName = "Alexa",
        LastName = "Ansley",
        Age = 24
    };
}
```

I tried global CSS, restart application, and nothing.

```
input[type="radio"]:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Try this link it could help > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025695/how-to-remove-the-square-border-from-around-a-button-which-has-already-been-visi

Comment: outline: none; ... Did not work.

Answer (score 0):

set this code:

```
@for (int i = 18; i < 36; i++) {
     <InputRadio Value="@i" style="border:none;"/>
     @($" Age {i}")<br />
}
```

or

```
 input[type="radio"]:focus {
   border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Did not work :_( ...But u gave me an idea: I created CSS: .out-border {  outline: none !important;  border: none !important;  .out-border:focus { border: none !important;  outline: none !important;  }. Then <InputRadio Value="i" class="out-border" />, and works fine! (CSS connoisseurs must be smiling)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the green border is because when you create a new Blazor app, the template has this css in the site.css file:

```
.valid.modified:not([type=checkbox]) {
    outline: 1px solid #26b050;
}
```

One way to remove the border from radio buttons would be to add `:not([type=radio])` to it like this:

```
.valid.modified:not([type=checkbox]):not([type=radio]) {
    outline: 1px solid #26b050;
}
```